# MySQL if condition for time difference

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I have this basic issue using if condition:

*This script works just fine*

```
SELECT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2017-09-26 03:11:46',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())< 1200  ,'yes','no')
```

*But it is not working when I do it this way*

```
if (SELECT (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2017-09-26 03:11:46',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) < 1200)
THEN
SELECT 'YES'

ELSE
SELECT 'NO'
```

Comment: `if` is only allowed in a programming block, such as a stored procedure or trigger.

Comment: So does it mean that the codes on the bottom is also working if I put it in SP?

Comment: . . It should work.

Comment: omg I'm so stupid, I've just tried it on SP and its working, thanks for this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example needs to be in a stored procedure. The first example is a standard DML statement and does not share the same syntax as stored procedures.

If you check here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

you can see that they state this explicitly

```
The IF statement for stored programs implements a basic conditional construct.
```